# How to do casbah bulk inserts

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

In casbah I see the following function defined on a MongoCollection:

```
def
insert[A](docs: A*)(implicit dbObjView: (A) ⇒ commons.TypeImports.DBObject, concern: mongodb.WriteConcern = writeConcern, encoder: TypeImports.DBEncoder = ...): TypeImports.WriteResult
```

If I understand this right you can pass a number of DBObjects to this function for a bulk insert.

My concern/question is that this is a list of parameters.  What if I have a huge bulk insert (say a couple hundred)?  Is there a limit of object that can be passed this way?

Comment: I don't understand the question fully. Do you ask how many arguments can be passed to the first parameter list (or to varargs in general)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit on the size of the document that can be used in a single command ~16mb so there is a limit on how many inserts you can do via that route.

However, if you use one of the `BulkOperationBuilders` released in Casbah 2.7 for MongoDB 2.6 it will automatically split the operation into batches so you can do larger bulk operations:

```
val collection = MongoClient()("test")("bulkOperation")
collection.drop()

// Ordered bulk operation
val builder = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation
builder.insert(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1))
builder.insert(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 2))
builder.insert(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 3))

builder.find(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1)).updateOne($set("x" -> 2))
builder.find(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 2)).removeOne()
builder.find(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 3)).replaceOne(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 3, "x" -> 4))

val result = builder.execute()
```

There are ordered or unordered operations see: http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/whats_new.html#ordered-unordered-bulk-operations